# SVN checkout under a different user name

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, subversion

When I ssh into my server I log in under root or my user on the system.

However, when I checkout from my svn repos then are then owned by either root or my user, and therefore all files deployed to my server come up with a 500 error on the server with the message "UID of script is less than MIN_UID".

When I FTP files to the server they are owned by user "Sites" so is there any way I can log in under root or my user and checkout files that are owned by "Sites".

What I don't really want to have to do is to have to manually `chown` all the files every time I checkout or update. I'd like it to happen automatically (or have to do it just the once on checkout).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in front of your svn commands:

```
sudo -u Sites
```